# How to show a modal window triggered by a button within a UIPopoverController?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I'm kind of new to iOS development and I'm working on making a LITE version of an existing app.

There currently is a Settings popover. In the popover there is a Full Version Info button.

I'm trying to attach code to the Full Version Info button to bring up another view (FullVersionInfoView.xib) that has an image and two buttons...one to go to a website and another to go to the App Store.

How do I load this view? Do I load the .xib directly or do I load the FullVersionInfoViewController?

And do I add this new view to the popover or the parent of the popover?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the new view controller's view as subview to popover's parent view controller. Moreover if the popover's parent view controller is a navigation controller you can push the new view controller.

Comment: how would I do that? I have an foo.xib and booViewController. I tried this `FooViewController *fvc = [FooViewController alloc];
    [[self.parentViewController addSubview: fvc ];` but it is asking for the UIView...how do I get the UIView?

Comment: [self.parentViewController.view addSubview: fvc.view];